# finding palindrome on single-tape turing machine without changing the word

Tags: graph, metaprogramming, turing-machines

It is quite easy to find palindrome replacing letters on both ends with (Φ).

```
 ΦabaΦ
 ΦΦbaΦ
 ΦΦbaΦ
 ΦΦbaΦ
 ΦΦbaΦ
 ΦΦbaΦ
 ΦΦbΦΦ
 ΦΦbΦΦ
 ΦΦbΦΦ
 ΦΦΦΦΦ
 ΦΦΦΦΦ
 ΦΦΦΦΦ YES
```

It is possible with changing a to A , and changing A to a at the end of task. But does anybody have an idea ,how to achieve this without using additional signs?

Comment: I have achieved that by using recursion. Post a comment, if you want to send you a solution. It is done in special turing machine emulation program.

Answer (score 1):

Moving of end characters can help:

```
 ΦΦabaΦΦ
 ΦaΦbaΦΦ
 ΦaΦbΦaΦ YES
```

or

```
 ΦΦabbaΦΦ
 ΦaΦbbaΦΦ
 ΦaΦbbΦaΦ
 ΦabΦbΦaΦ
 ΦabΦΦbaΦ YES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change a to A, and b to B, and ur end character would be a capital letter. (take the ascia value, and if it falls in the uppercase range, you know the end)
This assume your input is entirely lower case.

Answer (score 0):

For each possible symbol on the tape (which I assume are drawn from a finite set), you need a state, which I'll call "$X_LOOKING". Start at the left end and set the state to "$X_LOOKING" for the symbol $X that you find there. Move right until you hit the end and see if it matches $X.

When you move back left, you'll have to stop at the *2nd* letter instead of the first. For this maybe you can keep track of how many letters you've looked at on another area of the tape.

Comment: it is impossible to keep track of any number. The set is finite, although it is much more than two - it will be quite hard to do any "tracking".

Comment: Why can't you track the number? You didn't say the tape was unalterable, just the word on the tape.